# Apply current css to navigation in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am using a dynamic header for my page built in PHP and i am trying to apply the current CSS to the selected page. I can do this by defining class current in the html but this doesn't work with a dynamic header.

Here is my php header file what is wrong with my code. As far as I can tell the php statement should figure out the current page and apply the current css but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance for your help :). My website is: http://wonx.dk/phpintergrated/index.php

```
<?php
function get_current($title) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $title) !== false)
    echo 'class="current"';
}
?>


<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logofinal.svg"  alt="Devil Sheep Logo" /></a>

<label for="menuon">
<img src="img/menu.svg" alt="MENU"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menuon">

<nav>
      <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Home" >Home</a></li> <!--Sets the home tab to on meaning it is selected.-->
        <li><a href="aboutme.php" title="About Me">About Me</a><!--Whitespace causes problems with display:inline-->
           <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="aboutdropdown"><a href="aboutme.php" title="About Me">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.php" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="photogallery.php" title="Photo Gallery">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="recipe.php" title="Recipe">Recipe</a></li>
        <li><a href="song.php" title="Song">Song</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.php" title="CV">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="experiments.php" title="Experiments">Experiments</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" title="Contact Me">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you import the CSS? It may be something as small as you using the relative location of the CSS file rather than the absolute location.

Comment: It is in the pages does it need to be in the php document as well?

Comment: Where are you calling your `get_current()` function?

Comment: Well when you're using a shared header, you may have to use the absolute location of the css file. If you import it relative to the current directory and another file uses it that is not at the same location it will not import because the file will not exist in relation to where the header points. If you are importing like 
`<link relation="stylesheet" href="../Css/style.css">` you will want to use
`<link relation="stylesheet" href="http://Mysite/Css/style.css">`
instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a finite number of menu items.

declare an array with all your menu items

```
 $current['index.php'] = "";
 .
 .
 .
 $current['contact.php'] = "";
 $temp = $current;
 foreach($temp AS $key => $value)
 {
   if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $key) !== false)
    $current[$key] = 'class="current"';
 }
```

Now go to the html

```
  <li <?php echo $current["index.php"]?>><a href="index.php" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
 .
 .
 .
 <li <?php echo $current["contact.php"]?>><a href="contact.php" title="Contact Me">Contact Me</a></li>
```

The 
.
.
.
mean rinse and repeat.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put class on element itself, like:

```
<li><a href="index.php" title="Home" <?=get_current('home')?> >Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you want to specify another class to a link or somebody uses a CapiTalS within the title??

```
function get_current($title) {
  $uri = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if (strpos($uri, $title) !== false)
    return  'current'; //-- Don't echo in a function, return something
}
```

And in your HTML

```
<li>
  <a href="index.php" title="Home" class='<?php echo get_current('home');?>' >Home</a>
</li>
```